# apache cannot load perl module that is installed manulally using make and install

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

Perl - CGI

apache cannot load perl module that is installed manulally using make and install.
in apache logs it gives err saying - module not found in @INC .

Though modules installed via CPAN work fine .

Please Help

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib qw(/home/appsadm/Infoblox_Perl_API/Infoblox-6.0040000164053);
use lib qw(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/LWP/); 
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Infoblox::Session;

local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);   
    $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")    {
        read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    }else {
        $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
    }

    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);

    foreach $pair (@pairs)
    {
        ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);

        $value =~ tr/+/ /;

        $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

        $FORM{$name} = $value;
    }

    $username = $FORM{username};
    $password  = $FORM{password};

my $appliance = '161.19.15.8';

$session =  Infoblox::Session->new(  master => $appliance,  username => "admine", password=> "prafgd1"  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the modules are installed in `dir` and `dir` is not part of `@inc`, you can

```
use lib qw(dir);
```

at the start of your program, before you use the module.

Comment: i did that. use lib qw(/home/appsadm/Infoblox_Perl_API/Infoblox-6.0040000164053);
 but in the code when i use Infoblox::Session->new ,it gives err   .... Can't locate object method "new" via package "Infoblox::Session" (perhaps you forgot to load "Infoblox::Session"?) at /var/www/cgi-bin/infoblox_login.cgi line 31.

Comment: @user1579557: then add the relevant code to your question which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: i am new to stack overflow , my code is not being accepted ... why so ? is ther particular formatting ?

Comment: @user1579557: you should be able you click `edit` below your question and add your code... After the `use lib qw(/home/...);`, did you add `use Infoblox::Session;`?

Comment: posted the code... now error log says Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/LWP/ /home/appsadm/Infoblox_Perl_API/Infoblox-6.0040000164053 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /var/www/cgi-bin/infoblox_login.cgi line 5., referer: http://161.69.112.45/login.html

Comment: when i say locate UserAgent.pm , it is present at /usr/lib/per5.....CPAN/LWP/UserAgent

Comment: so you have say: `use lib qw(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN)`, that's the directory where LWP/UserAgent.pm resides. but it's a strange location if you installed it using `cpan`...

Comment: now it says : Can't locate CPAN/HTTP/Credentials.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN /home/appsadm/Infoblox_Perl_API/Infoblox-6.0040000164053 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 6., referer: http://161.69.112.45/login.html

Comment: i have prepared a desktop application using Tk , and it works fine for  evrything... now converting it to a web interface using apache is giving me a headache ...

Comment: locate Credentials.pm shows it present @ 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/HTTP/Credentials.pm

Comment: @user1579557: it seems to me that your installation is a bit of a mess... the modules you use are regular cpan installable modules, but it looks like you messed with the prefixes.. best fresh install them in the default locations.

Comment: i have installed using cpanm is that a problem ?

Comment: do u suggest i clear everything from my /usr/lib/perl5/ and reinstall everything ?

Comment: `cpanm` should be OK. You mention a module called `CPAN::HTTP::Credentials`; I think you mean `HTTP::credentials`, which would reside in `/usr/lib/.../CPAN`; but this modole is not mentioned in your code above...

Comment: it is present and says 
CPAN::HTTP::Credentials is up to date. (1.9600).. i also added use lib qw(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/) where it is showing with locate. actually it shows HTTP/Credentials.pm at multiple locations

Comment: so wat u suggest ... i jsut cannot proceed w/o this being fixed

Comment: i had also read that perl 5.10 has a better support.. but could not find how to perl install 5.10 on my centos 5.8

Comment: I'm afraid I'm fresh out of ideas at the moment. refresh the code in your question with what you've got now, maybe that gives me or others an idea...

Comment: about perl 5.10: even that is quite old. the current version is 5.16... get it from perl.org, or an additional repository for CentOS like repel...

Comment: m installing 5.16 . Do i need to reinstall httpd after installing perl ?

Comment: Please refrain from using the comments as an interactive debug session.